# Pass a parameter into an SQL file

Tags: postgresql

In Oracle we have a tiny sql file (truncate_table.sql) that calls a function that truncates a table:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FuncTruncTable executing...');
     IF ( FuncTruncTable(upper('&1'))=FALSE) THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FuncTruncTable failed');
     END IF;
END;
/
```

For `&1`, we pass `schema_name.table_name`.  I realize that table names in PostgreSQL are in lower case.
So, in PostgreSQL I tried

```
IF ( select FuncTruncTable(lower('&1'))=FALSE) THEN....;
```

This SQL file is called by a shell script (`truncate_single_table.sh`) that basically looks like this

```bash
TableName=$1
LOG_FILE=/some_dir/log/truncate_log.txt
sqlplus user_name/user_pass @/some_dir/sql/truncate_table.sql $TableName > $LOG_FILE
```

`truncate_single_table.sh` is called by another shell script `truncate_tables.sh`.

`truncate_tables.sh` assembles a bunch of tables and calls  `truncate_single_table.sh to truncate them one by one as follows:

```bash
. /some_dir/bin/truncate_single_table.sh schema_name.TABLE_1 NEW
. /some_dir/bin/truncate_single_table.sh schema_name.TABLE_2 APPEND
. /some_dir/bin/truncate_single_table.sh schema_name.TABLE_3 APPEND
```

and so forth.

`NEW` and `APPEND` are used in order to count the tables - the number of the tables that have to be truncated has to match the number of the actually truncated tables. If an error occurs, the job sends a warning because `(TotalNumber - number of errors) <> TotalNumber`.

I'm trying to convert the process to PostgreSQL.  I'm totally new to PostgreSQL.
Simply replacing

```bash
sqlplus user_name/user_pass @/some_dir/sql/truncate_table.sql $TableName > $LOG_FILE
```

with

```bash
psql -d "dbname=$dbname user='user_name' password='user_pass' host=$HostName" -f /some_dir/sql/truncate_gnxsawork_table.sql $TableName > $LOG_FILE
```

doesn't work.

Perhaps different options (other than `-d`, `-f`) should be used that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the table name to `psql` as a variable:

```bash
psql -v tabname="$TableName" -f script.sql -d ...
```

and use it in the script as

```
DO $$BEGIN RAISE NOTICE 'FuncTruncTable executing...'; END;$$;
SELECT NOT functrunctable(upper(:'tabname')) AS result \gset
\if :result
DO $$BEGIN RAISE NOTICE 'FuncTruncTable failed'; END;$$;
\endif
```

Comment: I'm gonna say "Wow!!".  It worked  )))  I wouldn't be able to find such a solution in a million years  )))  Thank you very much !!!   .....But now I'm facing another challenge.....   When calling sqlplus and a job gets executed successfully in Oracle it creates this message "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." ....and it gets written into a log file.  Is there anything similar in Postgres?  If Yes, how can I invoke and use it?

Comment: You can `RAISE LOG` in PL/pgSQL to write a log message.